# socket.io upgrade returns a different socket.id

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, upgrade

I have just upgraded from 1.3.7 to 1.4.5. I since noticed a difference in the socket.id. For example, prior to the upgrade, socket.id would be something like "K8JxW0Hy3djMo-GYAAAC". After the upgrade, socket.id is now something like "/#K8JxW0Hy3djMo-GYAAAC". 
As my application is checking socket.id, the app now crashes. I am wondering, from a high level, if anyone knows why this is?

My initial suspicion was that it was concatenating the namespace, as I use the default "/", but that did not lead me very far.

At no point in my app is the socket.id being updated etc, it is only ever retrieved. It is a sizable app, hence the lack of code in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I have since reverted back to the old version of socketio and the issue is not present, confirming it is an change put in a later version. I could not find any docs on this exactly, but as I am using default namespace "/", my optimistic self thinks that this is what is being added.

Please comment if anyone find docs to confirm why this has changed.

Comment: if it makes you feel better, socket.io has been a nightmare to maintain for me too. It breaks at every upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In a strange way, it does help. Nothing worse than thinking I'm the only one with issues. There's not much I can find regarding change logs, which could help.

Comment: There is an open issue in git for this https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2451 let's wait and see the response from socket io team

Comment: Thanks Sasi. I can at least relax now knowing it is indeed an issue with socket.